# Draw a tree from a matrix in r

Tags: r, tree

Let us consider the following tree.

[image]

which is described by the matrix below

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    3    2
[2,]    2    2    1    1
[3,]    3    2    3    1
[4,]    2    2    2    2
[5,]    1    1    1    1
[6,]    3    2    3    2
[7,]    1    1    3    1
[8,]    2    1    1    1
```

I have obtained previous image manually drawing the tree on: [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/).

Each row of the matrix has four entries and represents the levels of the tree. The first and the third levels (columns) can have three nodes (1, 2 or 3); the remaining levels (columns) can assume only two values: 1 or 2

I wonder whether there is a package in r to draw a tree from a matrix like M.

Comment: I don't understand how that matrix describes that tree.

Comment: Each row of the matrix has four entries and represents the levels of the tree. The first and the third levels (columns) can have three nodes (1, 2 or 3); the remaining levels (columns) can assume only two values: 1 or 2.

Comment: @Axeman each row is a path through the tree. For example, the farthest left branch corresponds to row 5: 1, 1, 1, 1. The farthest right branch corresponds to row 6: 3, 2, 3, 2. (You could imagine a 0th column that is always 'root'.)

Comment: @Mark, your matrix is unusual. I've never seen a matrix like that used to describe a tree. Does this representation have a name? You might want to look into the `igraph` package - it can definitely draw trees, but you'd probably have to figure out a transformation to get your matrix into a more standard format.